# get current month prints previos month

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the current month. we are in may now but a weird thing happens:

```
var thisDate = new Date();
console.log(thisDate); 
console.log(thisDate.getMonth());
```

Output:

```
Thu May 14 2020 12:25:19
4
```

The expected value is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMonth()` return number from 0 to 11, so just add +1 to that.

Answer (score 1):

The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Use this code

```
var thisDate = new Date();
console.log(thisDate); 
console.log(thisDate.getMonth() + 1);
```